# How could I integrate boostrap dropdown with angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make the dropdown with input function with boostrap style and angular.js

[image: inline]

http://egemem.com/theme/kode/v1.1/form-elements.html

However, It didn't work even I tried to use directive to avoid conflicting with jQuery

How could I integrate jQuery function with angular.js

## HTML

{"routes": "routes"}

## js

```
app.directive('customepicker
customepicker',function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'CE',
      replace: true,
      template: '<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" style="display: none;"> <option ng-repeat=" (departure, destinations) in routes">{{departure}}</option></select>',
    };
});
```

## output

[image: inline]

Answer (score 0):

Use [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

This is bootstrap adapted for use with Angular.

> This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on
>   Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or
>   Bootstrap's JavaScript is required.

Here is the section on [using dropdowns](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown):

> Dropdown is a simple directive which will toggle a dropdown menu on
>   click or programmatically.
>
> This directive is composed by three parts:
>
> ```
> uib-dropdown which transforms a node into a dropdown.
> uib-dropdown-toggle which allows the dropdown to be toggled via click. This directive is optional.
> uib-dropdown-menu which transforms a node into the popup menu.
> ```
>
> Each of these parts need to be used as attribute directives.

Comment: It seems Angular could NOT integrate with popular 3rd party js plugin well, such as bootstrap, jqeury, backbone. gotcha~~~ thank you